# Javascript image cycler

Tags: javascript, image, timer, slideshow

After the timer the image div goes blank instead of switching to the next picture. It is supposed to cycle images 1-4 and repeat indefinitely

```
$('.carouselImageJavascriptActive').removeClass('carouselImageJavascriptActive');
$(this).addClass('carouselImageJavascriptActive');
var imgs=$(this).attr('.carouselImage')
var self = $(this);
var myImage = new Array();
var x=0;

myImage[0]='img/image1.jpg';
myImage[1]='img/image2.jpg';
myImage[2]='img/image3.jpg';
myImage[3]='img/image4.jpg';

setTimeout(function() {

    var img = document.getElementById('.carouselImageJavascriptActive');
    img.src = myImage[x];
    x++;

    if(x >= myImage.length){
        x = 0;
    } 
},2000);
```

HTML

```
<div id='challengeTwoImageJavascript' class='sectionChallengeCarouselImage'>
    <img id='imgj1' imgn='1' class='carouselImage carouselImageJavascriptActive' src='img/image1.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgj2' imgn='2' class='carouselImage' src='img/image2.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgj3' imgn='3' class='carouselImage' src='img/image3.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgj4' imgn='4'class='carouselImage' src='img/image4.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of those images have an id of '.carouselImageJavascriptActive'.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have answered this question as I don't have enough time to elaborate at the moment. I'll get back to you in a couple of hours if someone doesn't answer by then

Comment: I changed it to document.getElementByClassName. Still doesn't work. THoughts?

Comment: @user1489691 Please show the rest of your code.  We're clearly missing something because you're using a `$(this)` selector when there is nothing for it to reference.